# How to extract binded file using batch script?

Tags: command-line, batch

I binded two files image1.png and image2.png using command copy /b image1.png+image2.png bindedimage.png.
How can i extract bindedimage.png to image1.png and image2.png?

Comment: Any particular reason you did this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: IMHO it would be better to put the two file inside another container, like a zip or 7-zip archive which will make them easy to extract. You can also disable compression if it's a waste of time (as is often the case with image files).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this reliably, since the information where file 1 ends and file 2 starts was not stored anywhere. They're just a single blob of bytes now.

However, if both files were PNGs, you can try to separate them by analyzing their structure: a PNG file always starts with the "signature" (bytes `8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a`) and always ends with an `IEND` chunk (`0000 0000 4945 4e44 ae42 6082`). Split the files at the place where the first IEND chunk follows the second signature. There is no program to do this, however.